# How to write files on external sdcard (physical card) with Phonegap/Cordova on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Is there a way to write to an external (physical) sd card (not the emulated) on android using Phonegap/Cordova? I'm struggling with this task, but since a lot of apps I use actually do that, I don't know why is so hard do achiev (if possible).

Comment: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails

Answer (score 0):

look to plugin cordova-plugin-file look to Android section, there's sdcard methods

Comment: The sdcard methods are just for the internal emulated sd card, not the external, unfortunatelly